# Using the modulus operator to display the current time

Tags: java

Disclaimer: Beginner question.

In a Java Exercise, we are asked to obtain the current time in milliseconds using System.currentTimeMillis(), then to obtain the seconds by dividing to 1000, and then to display the seconds using the modulus operator, that is, the number % 60. Then we are asked to display the minutes doing / 60, and then again % 60.

Can somebody explain in Layman's terms why was that % used in this simple program and how this program works? I know there are questions already on SO about how the modulus op. works, but this is a more practical case and seem not to be covered here. Thanks!

```
 public class Test {  

    public static void main(String[] args) {

long totalMilliseconds = System.currentTimeMillis();
long totalSeconds = totalMilliseconds / 1000;
long currentSecond = totalSeconds % 60;
long totalMinutes = totalSeconds / 60;
long currentMinute = totalMinutes % 60;
long totalHours = totalMinutes / 60;
long currentHour = totalHours % 24;

System.out.println("Current time is " + currentHour + ":" + currentMinute + ":" + currentSecond);



     }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The modulus operator computes the remainder of an integer division.

So let's take an example. Suppose 127 seconds are elapsed. That makes 2 minutes and 7 seconds, right? How do you compute that?

1. You divide 127 by 60 to get the minutes. The result is 2 minutes.
2. You compute the remainder of that division to get... the remaining seconds. That's what the modulus operator does. The result is 7 seconds.

The rest of the algorithm applies the same principle for hours. Maybe you'll understand things better by printing all the intermediate results to the console. But really, it's just arithmetics.

Comment: what does that last " % 24 " do, at the end? Could you be so kind to comment that line? I apologise in advance for being a novice at this.

Comment: Same thing, for hours. If the total hours is 26, that makes 1 day and 2 hours, right? 2 is 26 % 24.

Answer (score 0):

Given `a>=0` and `b>0`
`a % b` is the remainder of the division of `a` by `b`.

This means if `a >= n*b` for a natural number `n` we have

`a % b == (a - n*b) % b`

Let's say you have 359 seconds (= 5 minutes 59 seconds) and want to find out, the seconds in the minute.

`b = 60` is used here, so the result is the same as subtracting the largest number of **full minutes** from `a = 359` that can be subtracted without making the result negative.

In this case we have

```
359 % 60 == (359 - 5 * 60) % 60
         == 59 % 60
         == 59
```

It's similar for hours/minutes and days/hours.